# Automate nuget update-package operation on many VS solutions

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, nuget-package

I've got 10+ Visual Studio solutions that are referencing a nuget package.
When I decide to update that package in every solution it's a very long work to open each solution manually, update its package and check-in all changes to TFS. I'd like to "automate" this process with a batch operation that does it on behalf of me.

I've made some experiments with nuget.exe by command line but it doesn't care about TFS read-only files: it overwrites the content of my files without checking-out them so this way seems not the best way to do it.

Any other suggestion to achieve the aim?

Answer (score 2):

You can use nuget update command to do this. VS/TFS can detect the changes even thought you are running the command outside from VS. And usually, only "packages.config" file will be updated during the nuget package update.

Update:
Following is a simple code to find the solution files under the given path and update the nuget packages for the solution and then check in the pending changes via [TFS PowerShell CommandLets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/21/powershell-and-tfs-the-basics-and-beyond/) (You need to install "[TFS Power Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)" to use this commandlet). You can update according to your scenario.

```
param([String]$dirpath)

add-pssnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell;

Get-ChildItem -Path $dirpath -Filter *.sln -Recurse | ForEach-Object { & nuget update $_.FullName 2>1;  cd $_.Directory; get-tfspendingchange; new-tfschangeset}
```

Save the code as a powershell script and run it from Windows PowerShell with argument "-dirpath yoursolutionpath". It will run as following:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but in my description there is no  mention about checking-in nuget packages becase I don't do it. I wrote that I've got 10+ solutions under TFS that use a certain package but this doesn't mean that each solution puts under source control its packages. My purpose is to update a specific package via command line/powershell/don't know and make visual studio & TFS are able to see changed files (eg. the csproj file, packages.config file, etc..) so that I can check-in them under TFS.

Comment: @Luca Oops, sorry for misunderstanding your question, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Where should I use the update command? From powershell? Could you post a small example, please?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think we are very close to the solution. I've got a problem when running your script because it says that nuget is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. Should I import it in any way?

Comment: @Luca You need to download nuget.exe to your machine and set its path as environment path.

Comment: The problem with using `nuget.exe` is that it doesn't checks-out my files. I added nuget to evironment path and tried your script but still not working. When i execute `get-tfspendingchange` i get 0 pending changes. The version of my nuget.exe is `3.3.0`.

Comment: Are these files checked into Source Control? The changes should be tracked automatically if the files are tracked by TFS Version Control.

Comment: Yes, of course. The solution, csproj, and source code files are checked in into TFS. The only things that are not into TFS are the nuget packages.

Comment: @Luca What about the "packages.config" and "app.config" file?

Answer (score -2):

Download [Nuget Comanline](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html)

```
nuget.exe restore YourSolution.sln 
nuget.exe update YourSolution.sln
```

[Nuget Docs](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference)

Comment: _"but it doesn't care about TFS read-only files: it overwrites the content of my files without checking-out them"_